Helmholtz paraxial approximation
I have two questions regarding this case.
In our lecture it was said that once the paraxial approx. is applied, the field $\vec E$, no longer obeys the Maxwell euqations.
Why is that and how can one prove this statement? At the same time is there an intuitive explanation of this?
Then we follow this up by saying, for a gaussian beam that, the error becomes larger the smaller the waist of the radius $w_0$ is.
Which error are we talking about here?
Finally, regarding the Hermite-Gauss modes.
We say that these are a set of solutions to the paraxial wave equation and they describe the transverse spatial modes of optical fields in gaussian beam propagation.
I don't understand what it's meant with transverse spatial modes? What modes are there transverse to the beam propagation I assume.
